# How to delete a file with no extension?

Tags: c#

I'm developing a programm and the programm schould delete a cache. The only problem is that all the files in the cache have no extensions and always when I try to delete those files I get an exception: `The access to the path 'path' was denied.` So I don't know why this error occurs because I'm trying to delete a file and not a directory. I think it doesn't recognises the file as a file because of the missing extension.I've etried this:

```
DirectoryInfo cache = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"\Cache");
Console.WriteLine("Deleting Cache...");
foreach (var fi in cache.GetFiles())
{
    File.Delete(cache + @"\" + fi.Name);
    Console.WriteLine(cache + @"\" + fi.Name);
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

What else can I try?

Comment: Show the failing code

Comment: "i think he doesn't recognises the file as a file because of the missing extension" - that's nonsense. files can have no extension, and folders can have an extension as well. most likely there's something wrong with your code (which you ***did not share***), or the files in question simply are protected and you don't have access to them, for some reason.

Comment: `FileInfo` (which is the type of `fi`) declares a `.Delete()` method, so you could simply call `fi.Delete();` Though I'm wondering if it's the call to `.GetFiles()` which is throwing the exception. Can you confirm?

Comment: With ```fi.Delete();``` also occurs the same error with the missing path. Is a extension needed to delete a file? What other method can I use to get all the files in the directory?

Comment: Does your program output the correct path to the console? Can you cut and paste that output and use it in a command line to delete the file manually? Do you still get access is denied?

Comment: Now I just found the error: The programm was still opened in the background and that's the reason I couldn't delete the files. But thanks for your Help!

Comment: If an extension is needed to delete a file, how would you delete any file that doesn't have a file extension?

Comment: Side note: If your directories can be large (and even if not), I'd recommend using `EnumerateFiles` instead of `GetFiles`. Also you may consider just Deleting the directory entirely and recreating it since you're deleting all the files anyways (though doesn't work if there are subfolders you want to keep or if another thread may be writing to your cache)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems your file was still open, so you can't delete it. However, my original answer still applies:

Since you already have a `DirectoryInfo`, you dont need to concatenate the strings to get the file-name, just use `FileInfo.Delete`:

```
foreach (var fi in cache.GetFiles())
{
    fi.Delete();
}
```

You should avoid concatenating strings to build a path anyway, use [`Path.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=net-5.0):

```
DirectoryInfo cache = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "Cache"));
```